# showRoute() Smartface 4.5 version is not drawing the route on the map

Tags: smartface.io

previously while using Smartface 4.4, route on map view control used to work fine. But, after upgrading to 4.5, route is coming up. Its showing the pins and everything except route.

Can any one help in this?
Thanks in advance.

Here is my code,
`Pages.Page1.MapView1.showRoute(41.06, 24.054,24.08,41.097);`
But, its drawing a very small line. That too i need zoom in a lot to see that.
[image]

Comment: I tried showRoute() like that `Pages.Page1.MapView1.showRoute(41, 24, 24, 41);`. it works fine.Can you share your code?

Comment: edited my question with my code and screenshot