# MapView showRoute() function for Smartface 4.5 version is not drawing the route on the map

Tags: smartface.io

This is duplicate of issue at: [showRoute() Smartface 4.5 version is not drawing the route on the map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35264287/showroute-smartface-4-5-version-is-not-drawing-the-route-on-the-map)

I was hoping someone can answer this ASAP.

Code that fails is simply:

Pages.Page1.MapView1.showRoute(41.06, 24.05,24.08,41.10);

When I try to run this code, the MapView zooms in to the endpoint(24.08,41.10) at the maximum zoom level of 21 and only draws route from endpoint to the edge of the zoomed in window of the MapView. When I zoom out from this view, I can clearly see how the route gets "chopped off".

Comment: You are not supposed to open [duplicate questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: There is a known issue for iOS. It will be fixed in the upcoming releases of Smartface.

Comment: I am having this issue on Android.